# getClass().getResource("/") returns null in command line

Tags: java, maven, jar, classpath, classloader

I'm trying to read a file in my maven project at /src/main/resources/file.txt.

I'm using

```
URL url=this.getClass().getResource("/");
String filePath=url.getPath()+"file.txt";
```

url object gets the correct value when this is run thru eclipse.

But, when I package the jar and run it in command line:

```
jar -cp myjar.jar SampleTest
```

It returns null for 'url' object and throws a NullPointerException in the next line.

I have openend my Jar file using file browser and checked. It has the 'file.txt' in "/" location inside the Jar.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: you should try `URL url= getClass().getResource("/file.txt");`    `String filePath=url.getPath();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are (often) no directories inside jar files. Therefor it will return `null`.

---

If you want to get the file you could get that resource directly:

```
URL fileUrl = getClass().getResource("/file.txt");
...
```

Or simply:

```
InputStream fileInputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.txt");
```

Comment: Well, it works fine in eclipse. "/" points to the /target/classes directory when run in eclipse.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: *There are no directories inside jar files* - e.g. You cannot get a resource (directory) that doesn't exist. When you run the program from eclipse your classpath points to a file path/directory. In that environment you can get the directory information using `Class.getResource`.

Comment: Is it possible to get a directory URL in a jar using getResource("/dir") by tweaking the project pom.xml some way ??

Comment: It is possible but a hack, see [this page](http://www.uofr.net/~greg/java/get-resource-listing.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You should move that file into your CLASSPATH and get it like this:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");
```

Comment: You're assuming that's in the classpath.  Does your JAR have a manifest, with Class Path entries?  If not, add one.