# Java game error, input == null?

Tags: java

I am making a Java 2D game and I am a newbie to programming language and game devolpment, so any help would be superb for me.
Right, to start off I have an error in my java script, here it is:

Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

```
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
    at ca.gingerninja.game.gfx.SpriteSheet.<init>(SpriteSheet.java:19)
    at ca.gingerninja.game.Game.init(Game.java:55)
    at ca.gingerninja.game.Game.run(Game.java:78)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And here is a screenshot of my code:

```
public class SpriteSheet {

    public String path;
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public int[] pixels;

    public SpriteSheet(String path) {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(image == null) {
            return;
        }
```

And here is the error in the debug console:

```
public static BufferedImage read(URL input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("input == null!");
        }
```

If you need anymore code please ask me and i will show them. Please help me sort out this error.

Comment: Your code... throws an exception... when ... `input` is equal to `null`.

Comment: Triple check `path` and make sure that `getClass().getResource(path)` returns what you want (i.e. resource is correctly positioned)

Comment: What help do you need here? Can you specify the problem? The code seems to work exactly like you want it to..

Comment: @user35443 the last snippet is `ImageIO.read()` source from AWT, he/she did not write it...

Comment: Ok, AWT´s code throws an exception when `input` is equal to `null`. That means that `getResource(path)` returns `null`, which means that the resource could not be found. Is there any way to help?

Comment: (i am a he) there seems to be no problem at all in the directory but then when i debug/run it i get this: Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
 at ca.gingerninja.game.gfx.SpriteSheet.<init>(SpriteSheet.java:19)
 at ca.gingerninja.game.Game.init(Game.java:55)
 at ca.gingerninja.game.Game.run(Game.java:78)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that getClass().getResource(path) is returning a null value and not the resource the read method is expecting.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here, can you tell me what i could type into my script to sort out the problem?

Comment: can you paste the complete code? It is unclear where you are initializing the path variable.

Comment: Yes, but let me explain in detail. The line image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path)); is trying the read a resource returned by getClass().getResource(path). Based on the error it seems that the read method is not able to resolve the resource from the **path** you specified

Comment: the resource i am trying to get is a picture in the "res" folder and it is called "sprite_sheet.png"

Comment: @GaneshChithambalamA.S.: Please don't do that. We do not endorse that on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the resource needs to be in your classpath. You didn't post the path to your resource, but I will quote this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11116069/2591612) since it applies:

> There are (often) no directories inside jar files. Therefor[e] it will
>   return null.
>
> If you want to get the file you could get that resource directly:
>
> URL fileUrl = getClass().getResource("/file.txt"); ...
>
> Or simply:
>
> InputStream fileInputStream =
>   getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.txt");

Comment: Sorry, i am a newbie, can you please tell me where to type this?

Comment: You need to understand the explanation or you will run into this problem again and again.

Comment: I just don't understand it, I don't know what to type and where to type?

Comment: What is `path` initialized to?

Comment: Sorry i am a newbie what do you mean by intilazeid to?

Comment: Is it this bit:  public String path;

Comment: Please pick up a book on Java and programming. You need more help than we can give you here. We are not a debugging service.

Comment: This is what is it initialized to: public String path;

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using ['Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers'](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-06/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-developers).

I fixed it by changing the project's build path:

1. Right click on the project name under `Project Explorer`. E.g. "testGame".
   Click `Build path` --> `Configure build path...`, then add a suitable JRE System Library. I used `jdk1.7.0_80` since `jdk1.8` gave me issues.
2. The error persisted because I had another system library listed above the `jdk1.7.0_80` (I assume that library was being called instead of the `jdk1.7.0_80`.) The error was solved when I removed that library, leaving only the `jdk1.7.0_80` lib, and applied the changes.
3. If the first two steps do not work then try adding your resources file to the build path. See step 1. E.g. 'testGame/src' & 'testGame/res' share the same build path.